# FFT on Hamming Window Function

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, sampling, window-functions

I want to apply Hamming window function the Audio sample then find out its fft..

```
[y,Fs,bits] = wavread('file1.wav');
Nsamps = length(y); 
ham= hamming(Nsamps);
ham_fft = abs(fft(ham));
ham_fft = ham_fft(1:Nsamps/2); % discarding Half points
plot(ham_fft);
```

[image: This is my FFT of the song file1.wav]

I don't know whether i am getting the correct fft or not ..

Comment: You need first to multiply the window with the signal (`y`), in the time domain, than perform the `fft`. Actually you get the correct fourier transform of the window itself.

Comment: Anyway I believe that this question is absolutely unnecessary, as it is clearly answered in this [answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/18572/8202) to one of yours...

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure is kind of wrong. You should:

1. Read the signal from a file.
2. Create the Hamming window of the same length
3. Multiply window by signal (on sample-by-sample basis)
4. Take the FFT

Therefore code should be like:

```
[y,Fs,bits] = wavread('file1.wav');
Nsamps = length(y); 
ham= hamming(Nsamps);
y_ham = y.*ham';
ham_fft = abs(fft(y_ham));
ham_fft = ham_fft(1:Nsamps/2); % discarding Half points
plot(ham_fft);
```

Comment: I tried the following code but the problem is that the dimension of y and ham are not same so element by element multiplication is not possible ...
What else is can do?

Comment: Maybe the signal itself is also stored as a column vector, try `y_ham=y.*ham;`

Comment: Depending on dimensions of your signal you can either transpose it with `'` operator or not.

Comment: Note that you also have to define the X-axis. It can be written like that: `plot(linspace(0,Fs/2-1/Nsamps,Nsamps),ham_fft)`